# Parse.com: Cache Policy vs LocalDatastore

Tags: objective-c, caching, parse-platform, local-datastore

I am very new to Parse with IOS and I am very confused about Cache and LocalDatastore.
What is the different between kPFCachePolicyCacheOnly and fromLocalDatastore.
Should I use localDataStore intead of Cacheonly to support offline usability. 
Basically I want to make sure that when it's offline, the user can still get the information that he has achieved when he is online.

Thanks