# Parse: Relation between local datastore and cached queries results

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, parse-platform

Using Parse, I am a little confused about relations between The Local Datastore and cached query results.

1. Why cannot I set the cachePolicy when enable localDataStore?
2. For example, when I query a lot of portraits photos, do I need to pin them into the local database to get them quickly in the future because they won't exist in the cache forever?

Thanks! I am very appreciated

Comment: I found a similar question but without answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784313/parse-com-cache-policy-vs-localdatastore)